# How to rewrite the node ids that stored in .mtx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `.mtx` file that looks like below:

```
0 435   1
0 544   1
1 344   1
2 410   1
2 471   1
```

This matrix has shape of `(1000, 1000)`.
As you can see, node ids starts at `0`. I want to change this to start at `1` instead of `0`.
In other words, I need to add `1` to all the numbers in the first and second columns that represent the node ids.

So I converted `.mtx` file to `.txt` file and tried to add `1` in each first and second columns.

and simply added `1` to each row like below

```
import numpy as np 

data_path = "my_data_path"
data = np.loadtxt(data_path, delimiter=' ', dtype='int')
for i in data:
    print(data[i]+1)
```

and result was

```
[  1 436   2]
[  1 545   2]
[  2 345   2]
[  3 411   2]
[  3 472   2]
```

now I need to subtract `1` from third column, but I have no idea how to implement that.

Can someone help me to do that?

Or if there's any way to complete my goal way more easier, please tell me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you increment only the first column?

```
data[:, 0] += 1
```

You may want to have a look at [indexing in NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Additionally, I don't think the loop in your code ever worked:

```
for i in data:
    print(data[i]+1)
```

You are indexing with values from the array which generally is wrong and is surely wrong in this case:

> IndexError: index 435 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

You could correct it to print the whole matrix:

```
print(data + 1)
```

Giving:

```
[[  1 436   2]
 [  1 545   2]
 [  2 345   2]
 [  3 411   2]
 [  3 472   2]]
```